# Botão que vai para uma outra página e retorna o valor passado

Tags: jsp, demoiselle

Olá,gostaria de saber como faço um botão pra pegar dados de uma outra página...tipo se na página1 eu informo o protocolo e valido com um captcha e clico em enviar,gostaria de saber como faço nesse enviar pra pegar somente o protocolo que digitei na página passada .... exemplo tenho esta página com todos os protocolos quero pegar somente o que digitei[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o codigo que envia após preencher o protocolo e o campo do captcha aew tem o botão que envia                                                                            Segue o código vê se ta certo.....

```
public String insert() {
        try {
                if(ca.execute()){

                try {

                 this.getprotocoloString();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return protocolo;
}
```

Comment: Ricardo edite a pergunta com essas informações, não as coloque como comentario

Comment: Ainda nã consegui.....